# How to determine if Couchbase Server version supports the Extended Attributes (xattrs) feature?

Tags: java, couchbase

Does the Couchabase Java client provide a way to determine if the server supports extended attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's a code snippet:

```
CouchbaseCluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(host);
cluster.authenticate(username, password);
ClusterInfo info = cluster.clusterManager().info();
boolean xattrsSupported = info.checkAvailable(CouchbaseFeature.XATTR);
```